# How to allow access to rooted configuration files in ASP.NET and Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Tags: .net-core

We have an application that is deployed on Kubernetes. We also have Hashicorp Vault deployed for managing secrets. I do not want to code pulling the configuration from Vault. I want my application to be vault agnostic. Vault makes it easy to template out the secrets out to a file. The Vault agent will always save the file under `/vault/secrets/`. I tried to use the [IniConfigurationProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.ini.iniconfigurationprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) by adding an option file from `/vault/secrets/`.

However, the problem in ASP.NET, the configuration system uses a `IFileProvider` that prevents reading files outside of the application root. This is a required security feature to prevent path traversal vulnerabilities.  I am trying to determine a way to explictly allow a certain path such as `/vault/secrets/secrets.json` or `/vault/secrets/secrets.ini`.

I can see the configuration provider types based on `FileConfigurationProvider` get initialized with a `FileConfigurationSource` class. This class has a `FileProvider` property. I tried a few months back to get this to work, but never could. Unfortunately, I do not currently have some code to share.

For now, I am using an entry point script that checks if the secrets file exists and if it does, `source` it into the current processes environment variables and then launch the dotnet application.  However, this solution relies on having a shell. I'd would really like to be able to use the chiselled Ubuntu base images.

**Question**: Is there a way to add a File Provider for a specific file source to allow access to a rooted folder such as `/vault/secrets/secrets.ini`.